# How to add an xml file to erlang edoc documentation

Tags: xml, documentation, erlang

I want to add the content of an xml file to the documentation created with edoc for a module.

I have a well documented module but I want to add more functions from a xml file.

I would like to add "Module:fun_name" functions as gen_server do it in its documentation.

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/doc/src/gen_server.xml

But I just want to use the xml file only for the "Module:fun_name" functions and the module edoc tags for the others functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any HTML markup in the edoc documentation sections, so I guess you should be able to create an iframe that shows the xml file as part of the module-level documentation.